# Xamarin Android control text color through a style

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

For my Xamarin Android screens, I want all EditText elements to use a white font.  Below is the current incarnation of my styles.xml file for my Android project.  How would this be changed to ensure all text in any EditText is white?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">#333333</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You would need to have a style that has a parent of `@android:style/Widget.EditText` that you can then override in your `MyTheme` by setting `<item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all EditText elements to use a white font.

As @Jon Douglas said, you should use `editTextStyle` item attribute in your `MyTheme`, modify your `styles.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        ...
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
   </style>

   <style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
       <item name="android:background">#333333</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

Effect :

[image]